# Change width of custom UIControl and keep centered with Autolayout

Tags: ios, width, autolayout, uipagecontrol, uicontrol

I have a problem with an UIControl and Autolayout. 
I created a custom UIControl, then I add it with Interface Builder and then add the constraints. 
The control is similar to UIPageControl and works like this, for every page, one dot is added and the width of the control changes. The problem is I don't know how to resize the UIControl programmatically and keep the control centered with Autolayout.

I attached a picture where you see one of the problems, the size, particularly the width.
Yellow part is centered, but dots are out of the box.

Thank you!

[image]

**EDIT 1**

Here is the code when I update dots count:

```
- (void)reloadNumberOfPages:(NSUInteger)pages {

    // Remove previous images
    for (UIView *v in self.subviews) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }

    // Change size
    CGFloat width = _dotSize.width * pages;
    CGPoint center = self.center;

    // Change size
    self.frame = ({

        CGRect frame = self.frame;
        frame.size.width = width;
        frame.size.height = _dotSize.height;
        frame;

    });
    self.center = center;

    // Add images
    CGFloat offSet = 0.0;
    for (int x = 0; x < pages; x++) {

        // Image
        UIImageView *dot = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_dotOFF
                                             highlightedImage:_dotON];
        dot.frame = CGRectMake(offSet, 0.0, _dotSize.width, _dotSize.height);
        dot.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(dot.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) / 2.0);
        dot.tag = x;
        [self addSubview:dot];

        // Añadimos offSet
        offSet += CGRectGetWidth(dot.bounds);

    }

}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I'm trying with "intrinsicContentSize" but it doesn't work

```
- (void)reloadNumberOfPages:(NSUInteger)pages {

    // Add images
    CGFloat offSet = 0.0;
    for (int x = 0; x < pages; x++) {

        // Image
        UIImageView *dot = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_dotOFF
                                             highlightedImage:_dotON];
        dot.frame = CGRectMake(offSet, 0.0, _dotSize.width, _dotSize.height);
        dot.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(dot.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) / 2.0);
        dot.tag = x;
        [self addSubview:dot];

        // Añadimos offSet
        offSet += CGRectGetWidth(dot.bounds);

    }

    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];

}

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    return CGSizeMake(_dotSize.width * _numberOfPages, _dotSize.height);
}
```

Comment: How are you changing the width? Intrinsic content size? Show code.

Comment: Is the yellow box in your screenshot the background color of this controller? I.e., are the dots flowing outside its frame? And are you setting the constraints in IB or in code?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using autolayout to position your custom view, you shouldn't be setting its frame or center. Get rid of the `self.frame =` and `self.center =` lines and implement `intrinsicContentSize`:

```
-(CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    return CGSizeMake(_dotSize.width * pages, _dotSize.height);
}
```